# Why can't I debug C# code in Visual Studio Code despite installing extensions?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, visual-studio-code

I try to debug easy C# Hello World code, I followed the guide by Microsoft https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/with-visual-studio-code. I can run code via Terminal dotnet run but I can't debug.

I got error

> "You have any extension for debugging C#"

but I have "C# for Visual Studio Code (powered by OmniSharp)" and I additionally installed ".NET Extension Pack".

I read documentation form Microsoft and few other tutorials and i have any idea why it doesn't work. I send screenshot of error.

[image]

Comment: Try restarting VS Code. Also, your project folder is open in VS Code?

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Run` > `Add configuration...` and select `.NET Core Console App` for debugging.